# index logic in combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox, indexing

I have combobox1 and comboox2 and in combobox1 my elements are A,B,C and combobox2 a,b,c,d,e,f...And I added this elements using property screeen(I mean not with code).

```
       combobox1                     combobox2
    ---------------               ---------------
           A                            a
           B                            b
           C                            c
                                        d
                                        e
                                        f
```

A related a,b,c and B related b,c and C related d,e,f.

When I choose "A" I want to see just a,b,c ; when select "B" just b,c etc.

Can I give an index number of combobox1's items? When I choose "A" I want to see just "a","b","c" elements(I mean 0,1,2 indeks numbers) 
When I choose "B", just b,c (I mean 1,2 indeks numbers).
I want to do like that cause if there is no index numbers I have to make all relationship with writing codes.I wrote a little code below but it is long way.

Index logic is better, sure if there is index logic in combobox :)

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     comboBox2.Items.Clear();
     switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
      {
        case "A":
           comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });
           break;

        case "B":
           comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "b", "c" });
           break;
      }
      comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combobox's elements filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630464/comboboxs-elements-filtering)

Comment: You can not hide elements from combobox2. So it is better to do the above way

Comment: @PraVn when I choose "A" just show me a,b,c... I can't do ? why ?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the case statement by indexing into a structure.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> items = 
      new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() { {"A", new List<string> {"a", "b","c"} } };

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     combobox2.DataSource = ltems[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];
     combobox2.DataBind();
   }
```

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way just using the combobox to do what you want.Where is the data coming from cant you dynamically popuplate the combobox, in auto way?

Comment: Cause I want to do this : when I choose "A" I want to see in comboBox2 just 1,2 index numbers of elements.same "B" I want to see in comboBox2 just 4,5,6 index numbers of elements.

Comment: I think you offer like my code above.And maybe my question meanless.Ok then forget about it.
   Also; Can I do using with xml.Country's(comboBox1) and city's(comboBox2) relationship I want to do.And sorry for a lot of question